# Laptop LCD T-Con

Tags: laptop, lenovo-laptop, laptop-repair, laptop-display

Is the t-con (timing control) board for a laptop lcd panel built into the panel itself, or is it a separate part that can be replaced like it is in televisions and desktop monitors?

From what I can tell, the board (at least in newer models) is considered to be part of the screen, and while it's technically removable from the panel, its also attached in a way that you would need very specialized equipment (beyond soldering iron) to loosen the connection and reattach a new one ones in order for a 'parts swap' to be done properly.  Is this accurate?

Comment: not sure about t-con board, but I know (at least on older models) there's a board that's either in between, or on the lcd panel (but usually removable in some way) that's the inverter which changes dc to ac and also jacks up the voltage. It may also house the t-con module.

Comment: I believe your right.  I'm aware of the switching board being a standard component that is "removable" if you have proper equipment (new models are so size-conscious that they are glued or soldered somehow,  and no longer utilize a serviceable connector.  I have a friend's laptop with obvious t-con malfunction, and while trying to diagnose the problem, found that the right side connector can have pressure applied and the screen errors change (these a ribbon on both L & R sides, like a t-con).  So it seems that the t-con is indeed built into the switching board, and is basically part of the lcd